# Can we do script to auto restart for Services if the VM Agent status is not ready using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

This is my current scenario:
VM status is "Running",  VMAgent is "Not Ready", Windows Azure Guest Agent  service is "Stopped".

I will manually start Windows Azure Guest Agent whenever my VMAgent is not ready.

So is there any script I can write using Powershell to automatically Start the service whenever VMAgent is not ready ?

[WMStatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5od1.png)

[VMAgentStatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eudvB.png)

[Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AySuA.png)

Comment: Maybe better an idea would be to find out why the agent is not being run?

Comment: I don't know. Sometimes we are facing this problem. not always

Comment: The **VM Status is running**. The **agent status only not ready**. and the services for **Windows Azure Guest Agent is stopped**. 

please have a look with the picture i shared in my post. you will know better.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, I'm afraid you cannot achieve it through a script to automatically start the service outside the VM. Please take a look at the description of the VM Agent:

> The VM Agent has a primary role in enabling and executing Azure
>   virtual machine extensions. VM Extensions enable post-deployment
>   configuration of VM, such as installing and configuring software. VM
>   extensions also enable recovery features such as resetting the
>   administrative password of a VM. Without the Azure VM Agent, VM
>   extensions cannot be run.

In this situation, what you can do is interact with VM through the remote connection and manually start the services inside the VM. For more details about the VM Agent, see it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows).

Comment: How if I save the script in the VM itself and run it ? It is possible right ..

Comment: @Pravindmaha That's OK, but you also need to connect into the VM and run the script. You cannot execute the script outside the VM. This is the problem.

Comment: Why not we script in this way ? 

1) Check the **VM Agent Status**
2) If VM Agent Status is good, not require to restart the service.
    If VM Agent Status is not good, need to restart the service.

Comment: @Pravindmaha Do you read the description of the VM Agent? You cannot control the VM outside when the agent is not ready.

Comment: @Pravindmaha I already shown the link at the end of the answer.

Comment: we are not controlling from outside the VM. we write and run the script inside the VM only.

Comment: @Pravindmaha Yeah, I know that. Where do you run the script? inside the VM or outside?

Comment: @Pravindmaha So you need to remote connect into the VM inside. Not outside the VM. Can you understand it?

Comment: yes i understand it. and that is what I wanted too.

Comment: @Pravindmaha There are only two ways to remote connect into the VM as I know, one is RDP, and another is WINRM. The former is a default way. The latter is custom and if you do not set it, you cannot use it. So I recommend the RDP.

Comment: @Pravindmaha Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -Name <VM-name> -Status
if($VM.VMAgent.Statuses.code -eq 'ProvisioningState/succeeded'){
    Write-Host $VM.VMAgent.Statuses.Message 
}else{
    Start-Service $AzureAgentServiceName
}

**I tried this coding but still not working..**

Comment: @Pravindmaha You run the script inside the VM? I don't think the VM Agent status is realtime info when the agent is not good.

Comment: @Pravindmaha I did not see any update for the question, do you solve the problem or still want to solve it?!